# Почему гугл не видит мой сайт?

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

Не могу понять почему гугл не находит мой сайт. Прописал ключевые слова, сделал все настройки, копирую ключевое слово в строку гугла, но он не находит. На W3C нет ошибок, все норм. Кто то может подсказать в чем дело?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="помощь в продвижении на кикстартере">
<meta name="keywords" content="продвижение на кикстартере, кикстартер, kickstarter">
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow, noodp">
<meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow">
<meta name="google" content="notranslate">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Ссылка на сайт на всякий случай [тут](https://advance.co.ua/)

Comment: Ключевые слова давно игнорируются всеми поисковиками

Comment: А как по другому? подскажите где почитать?

Comment: Просто делайте хороший сайт с хорошим контентом, и поисковики проиндексируют ваш контент

Answer (score 1):

Ваш веб-сайт представляет бизнес-компанию, однако не имеет никакой информации о вашем бизнесе.

Ваш веб-сайт не имеет информации о персоне или организации ответственной за содержание всего веб-сайта и за содержание каждой веб-страницы. Это противоречит следующим пунктам требованиям Гугл для содержания высокого уровня из ***Search Quality Raters Guideline of Google***:

> ● Who (what individual, company, business, foundation, etc.) is responsible for the
> website.
>
> ● Who (what individual, company, business, foundation, etc.)
> created the content on the page you are evaluating.

Перевод мой:

*Кто (какой человек, компания, бизнес, фонд и т. Д.) несет ответственность за веб-сайт.
Кто (что индивидуально, компания, бизнес, фонд и т. Д.) создал контент на странице.*

Ваш веб-сайт не имеет структурированных данных поэтому он недоступен как **[богатый результат](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/12/rich-results-tester.html)** в результатах поиска Гугл.

Проверьте **[проблемы производительности вашего веб-сайта с аудитом от Lighthouse](https://lighthouse-dot-webdotdevsite.appspot.com/lh/html?url=https://advance.co.ua/)**.

В настоящем виде ваш веб-сайт не внушает доверия и противоречит требованиям Гугл Экспертиза, Авторитетность, Надежность (Expertise, Authoritativeness, Trustworthiness - EAT).

Читайте дополнительно:

- **[Official Google Webmaster Central Blog: More guidance on building high-quality sites](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/05/more-guidance-on-building-high-quality.html)**
- **[Content creation for EAT](https://nikantmark.com/blog/eat.html)**

Answer (score 0):

> почему гугл не находит мой сайт. Прописал ключевые слова

**Причина - низкая релевантность сайта по запросам.**

**Ключевые слова отсутствую в теге title.**

Пример текста

*title Продвижение на Кикстартере - Advance /title*

**Отсутствует заголовок h1, в котором должны быть ключевые слова.**

Пример текста

*h1 Помощь в продвижении на Кикстартере /h1*

Ваша структура ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Робот Поисковой Системы (ПС) не может отнести ваш сайт к вашей тематике. Первый заголовок в коде - "Знакомство".

*Найдите информацию и ознакомитесь с SEO-рекомендациями по оформлению заголовков h1-h6.*

Недостатком еще есть то, что у вас одностраничник. 
Грубо говоря, при поиске пользователем информации, ПС покажет сайт, который может максимально ответить на запрос пользователя.

Посмотрите конкурентов, сколько страниц имеют они по вашему запросу.

Для вас было бы лучше выбрать запрос, который будет менее конкурентный и заточить ваш лендинг под этот запрос. Или развивайте сайт, делайте больше тематических страниц.